# How to log the places you visited as detailed as possible?

Tags: online-resources, maps

There are different services allowing you to map you visits. In the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) there were 2 examples ([Example 1](http://www.amcharts.com/visited_countries/) and [Example 2](http://www.traveltip.org/countries_visited.php)) given recently.

As a travel geek I would like to have a as detailed overview as possible of all my trips. The issue I have with services so far is that they are limited on country level, which means that my personal travelmap is a bit misleading. I have been in Brasil, although I have only been in [Oiapoque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oiapoque).

Is there an online service similar to the mapping service mentioned earlier that allow mapping on a very detailed level? I would consider a mapping on provinces or counties, to be quite accurate enough.

Comment: It will make it easier for bad people and governments to spy on you (-;

Answer (score 8):

I use [TripIT](https://www.tripit.com/) to manage most of my travel plans, itineraries and reference codes, and a nice side-effect of this is that you can pull out reports from TripIT by country, city, and I think even district (I only have the free version, not the TripIT Pro version)

One of the things I did look at using using though is [Tripline](http://www.tripline.net/). It lets you do not only maps and routes, but animated ones as well - to show your travel over time.

Comment: So is it possible to get the reports from the free version? What do I need to select if this is the case?

Answer (score 7):

I use [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/preview).

I basically annotate my travel on a city (or town) level, placing a marker on each one I've visited. In one layer I've got markers for any place that I've spent the night at. In another layer are places I've visited on day trips (but not stayed the night). Each layer has different markers on the map. You could add finer granularity of you like.

Answer (score 5):

I have a [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) blog and a plugin called [Geo Mashup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/geo-mashup/). It allows to put a "pin" on each place you want. You can pin a photo, a blog post, etc. also you can make/show routes drawing lines. You can see the plugin in action [in my blog](http://apeadero.es/) (Spanish only), zoom out to see a lot more points (by default I have set the plugin to show the latests pins, but you can choose to show a place or the whole world).

UPDATE: Today I've found a site called [The Best Travelled](http://thebesttravelled.com) that allow to upload a blog posts, images and so and has a more detailed travel map. See [an example here](http://thebesttravelled.com/en/travellersSingle/liuoi/).

Answer (score 3):

I have google location history enabled. It's a bit creepy but it's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Evernote does the job for me.

In addition its accompanying apps like Evernote Food and Skitch you can be as detailed as you want. Automatic geo tagging of the notes is of great help as well.

The desktop version of the app uses OpenStreet maps. It is possible to display the geo tagged notes on the map.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed using @jpatokal's tool [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/). For me it's difficult to spend so much time putting in flights such as in TripIt which IMO takes a decent amount of time to chart out things.

OpenFlights is easy and simple to use without any hassles. Best part is it lets me choose itineraries I have traveled on, airline providers, regions of the world etc. without any regard to specific detail. If you like specific detail, you can still enter it though.

Answer (score 0):

I use foursquare. I make some notes, pictures and places. Also I get feedback from where is good place to eat.

On the app Foursquare is not friendly to see the log, but on the site it is so nice.